# Why So Many Cases When Defining Comp?

Tags: clojure

The core.clj code for Clojure itself (available at https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) gives the following definition for `comp`:

```
    (defn comp
     "Takes a set of functions and returns a fn that is the composition
       of those fns.  The returned fn takes a variable number of args,
       applies the rightmost of fns to the args, the next
       fn (right-to-left) to the result, etc."
       {:added "1.0"
        :static true}
       ([] identity)
       ([f] f)
       ([f g] 
          (fn 
            ([] (f (g)))
            ([x] (f (g x)))
            ([x y] (f (g x y)))
            ([x y z] (f (g x y z)))
            ([x y z & args] (f (apply g x y z args)))))
       ([f g & fs]
          (reduce1 comp (list* f g fs))))
```

I'm new to Clojure and trying to understand both the technical side and idiomatic style sides of it and I'm wondering what the reason is for including so many cases when two functions are passed into `comp`. Why bother with the [x y] and [x y z] cases at all?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is done for efficiency.  `apply` is probably a little bit costly, and the 1, 2, and 3 -argument cases are common, so it doesn't hurt to add a few lines of code to handle them without calling `apply`.  One wouldn't want  `comp` to be costly--one wouldn't want people to have to avoid it for the sake of efficiency--so it's worth making it as efficient as possible for the most common cases.

Comment: Right. To see this additional application costs, you can take a look at the AFn.java in clojure's source (https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java) There you can see, that calling a function (e.g. calling `invoke` method) well just calls it. And applying (`applyTo` method) calls `invoke` in a switch on the arguments' length + some additional  utility methods. So the penalty is obvious. You will see this approach everywhere in clojure's core, for example `map` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Mars said, this is done for efficiency. Dispatching directly is faster than using `apply`. Unrolling functions like this is quite common to speed up the performance, `juxt` is unrolled in a similar fashion.